# Fullscreen console window using Visual Studio on Windows 11

Tags: c++11, console-application, windows-11

`SendMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);`

I've been using this line of code at the start of my `int main()` to make the console window fullscreen, and it works on the computer I was using with Windows 10.

I recently bought a new computer with Windows 11, and this command no longer works.

Is there a different way to make this work in both Operating Systems?

Comment: Have you tried to check values returned by `GetConsoleWindow()`, `SendMessage()`, `GetLastError()`? If not, why don't you apply any effort to research reasons of your issue?

Comment: I have no clue what this command does code wise, i just know that if I put it at the beginning of my source code the window goes fullscreen, but not on Windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, even with C++, and C, both cannot set the console to fullscreen mode, without assistance. This is caused by newer security on Windows 11.

However, two of the ways to do it is setting the Console Settings through Visual Studio, or by running it first time, and set the settings through the console settings.

This is through my observation with the situation, and I might be either right or wrong or in between, so take the answer with a grain of salt.